# Trying to create a shortcode to display categories with a specific product tag

Tags: php, shortcode, sql

I currently have the following and it is not working:
If I put the shortcode [tagtagtag=246] i get an array to string error

```
function get_categories_with_product_in_tag( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit' => 10,
        ), $atts,'tagtagtag'  );
    global $wpdb;
    $html = "";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        
        "SELECT categories.* FROM ".
        "{$wpdb->prefix}terms categories ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ctax ON (categories.term_id = ctax.term_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships crel ON (crel.term_taxonomy_id = ctax.term_taxonomy_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts posts ON (posts.ID = crel.object_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships trel ON (posts.ID = trel.object_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ttax ON (trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms tags ON (ttax.term_id = tags.term_id) ".
        "WHERE ".
        "ctax.taxonomy='product_cat' ".
        "AND posts.post_type = 'product' ".
        "AND posts.post_status = 'publish' ".
        "AND ttax.taxonomy = 'product_tag' ".
        "AND tags.term_id = %d ".
        "GROUP BY categories.term_id",
        $atts['tag_id']
    ) );
    $count = $wpdb->num_rows;
    if($count >0){
        $html .="<table>";    
    foreach($result as $r){
        $html .="<tr>";
        $html .="<td>".$r->post_title."</td>";
        $html .="<td><a href='".get_the_permalink($r->ID)."'>".$r->post_title."</a></td>";
        $html .="</tr>";
    }
    $html .="</table>";
    }

return $html;
}

add_shortcode('tagtagtag', 'get_categories_with_product_in_tag');


**EDIT:**

so i have simplified my query to just sql with the following:

    SELECT wp_terms.* 
    FROM wp_terms 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
         INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS ctax ON wp_terms.term_id = ctax.term_id  
         WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
  AND wp_terms.slug = 'testingtag';


This query gives me an empty set even though I have a product with 'testingtag' within the categories. 

**I have the folowing two other queries ( basic ones ) :
-this query shows all categories:**

    SELECT wp_terms.* 
    FROM wp_terms 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
         INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS ctax ON wp_terms.term_id = ctax.term_id  
         WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
  AND wp_terms.slug = 'testingtag';


**And show all products with the tag 'testingtag'**

    SELECT posts.ID AS product_id,
       posts.post_title AS product_title
FROM wp_posts AS posts,
     wp_terms AS terms,
     wp_term_relationships AS term_relationships,
     wp_term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy
WHERE term_relationships.object_id = posts.ID
  AND term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
  AND term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
  AND posts.post_type = 'product'
  AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_tag'
  AND terms.slug = 'testingtag';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your attributes in the shortcode as key-value pairs, and use them in php as an array as follows:

```
[tagtagtag tag_id=246]

function get_categories_with_product_in_tag( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT categories.* FROM ".
        "{$wpdb->prefix}terms categories ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ctax ON (categories.term_id = ctax.term_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships crel ON (crel.term_taxonomy_id = ctax.term_taxonomy_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts posts ON (posts.ID = crel.object_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships trel ON (posts.ID = trel.object_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ttax ON (trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) ".
        "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms tags ON (ttax.term_id = tags.term_id) ".
        "WHERE ".
        "ctax.taxonomy='product_cat' ".
        "AND posts.post_type = 'product' ".
        "AND posts.post_status = 'publish' ".
        "AND ttax.taxonomy = 'product_tag' ".
        "AND tags.term_id = %d ".
        "GROUP BY categories.term_id",
        $atts['tag_id']
    ) );
}
add_shortcode('tagtagtag', 'get_categories_with_product_in_tag');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

Comment: hi I edited my answer. is this more along the lines of what's needed? I still can't get it to work

Comment: Yes you should now get the value passed in the $atts['tag_id'], just remember to add it to the shotcode as [tagtagtag tag_id=246]. You don't really need the "$atts = 
 shortcode_atts( array(...." part, it is just to set defaults for values in case they are not specified in the shortcode, so you can remove those lines.

Check that your SQL query is working correctly by running the query directly in SQL or phpmyadmin and just filling all the values.

Comment: thank you. pls see my edit